# Chaincode peer is restarted

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Suppose if the peer is down, What will happen to the chaincode which was instantiated previously ?

If the peer is back up again, should the chaincode instantiated again ? ( In Ethereum, contract always stays as part of the ledger) . I am bit confused as the chaincode is in spawned as a docker container

Answer (score 0):

No need to instantiate again. peer should do that automatically.